# How can I manage python search paths or references in Visual Studio for Python files which are not part of a solution?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have a pretty specific problem regarding the my python setup. I need to reference python libraries made of .py files which are on my HD, but under a peculiar form of cloud-based version control. It is not possible to move those files elsewhere and I cannot add them to a python solution from VS(using VS2017). Basically, these are historically grown .py files right next to each other which reference each other. I would like to use VS2017 to work on and execute these python files and be able to reference the "neighboring" files without including them in a solution.

When I add these files to a python solution test.sln and adapt the search paths, everything works perfectly fine. I can reference anything, intellisense works, all good.

The modifications to the search paths are, as far as I can see, exclusive to test.sln. I added the source directories to the PYTHONPATH environment variable and disabled the "ignore global paths" option in VS, but still, referencing the .py files with each other without adding them to a solution does not work.

I can't find solution-independent reference search paths for VS, which would solve my problem. Is there a way to add default search paths for VS, or something like that?

```
# references:
import os
# works
import numpy as np
# works
import custom_file
# throws modulenotfound error

# do_stuff...
```

Example above.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could try adding the path to them to the [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) search path list via Python code at start up time.
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `sys.path.extend([path/to/custom_file_dir])` before trying to import the custom_file.